# x command line utility?

Tags: command-line, ssh, xorg

What is the use of x command line utility? What are the features of x command line utility and how is it different ffrom SSH utility?

Comment: This is kind of question better asked more narrowly and/or searched for in an easily searchable resource and not in other programmers' minds (generally google and wiki, often documentation - in this case propably man pages).

Comment: x as in /usr/bin/X? That is the Xorg server, and by its definition not a command-line utility..

Comment: This question needs to explain what the "x command line utility" being named actually is.  The X display server that others have guessed at is named `X`, not `x`, and is difficult to confuse with SSH.  People are even having to guess what platform this command line utility exists on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the x command line utility you refer to is. If you meant the X windowing system, then using an X interface or a shell interface has the same advantages and disadvantages as using any GUI or CLI app.

GUIs have discoverability; someone can look at a well-designed GUI and understand how to perform all the available functions. A command-oriented app requires reading documentation and familiarity. It's more often power users and administrators.

CLIs have scriptability. Sets of commands can be stored in files and executed non-interactively, repeatably, or against many hosts simultaneously. Commands can also be made in chains: in the Unix world, one-liners are common where many commands are chained with the output of one being the input to the next.

CLIs require less support; a Linux server running only in text mode can be fully functional with far less software and data.

CLIs are faster. A strong typist can easily accomplish tasks more quickly than using a GUI if in a good command line. (a full featured one, that is: using DOS' command.com isn't comparable to using GNU bash)

GUIs can interact with other GUI-based applications: for instance, you can drag and drop a picture file from Windows Explorer into Microsoft Word without typing (or even necessarily knowing) the picture's full location on disks.

GUIs are often more difficult, both to develop (they require separate libraries and a fair bit of code compared to a command line app) and to design (a poorly designed GUI will reduce functionality and user experience).

There are many other considerations when considering GUIs v. CLI, but these are some of the key considerations.